# What is the difference between Interbase and Firebird?

Tags: firebird, interbase

I'm interested in a broad overview of how they are diverging and why.

Comment: Please feel free to edit/improve this question if you know more about the topic: I've asked it mainly as an excuse to save [tag:interbase] which currently exists on only one question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683580/firebird-vs-interbase

Comment: @Colin that link is dead for me, can you still see it?

Comment: Nope. And here I thought linking within the SE family was pretty safe...

Comment: @Colin'tHart, the link is fine but not visible to all. You need 10K rep I think to see deleted answers.

Answer (score 3):

InterBase version 6 [was released](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InterBase#Open_source) under an open-source license in mid-2000, and [was immediately forked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebird_%28database_server%29#History) to become the Firebird project.

Later versions of InterBase reverted to closed-source and the projects have diverged. Both are still actively developed. Developer’s tools and libraries [traditionally support both servers](http://firebirdsurgeon.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/differences-between-firebird-and.html) but they are [growing apart](http://theprofessionalspoint.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/interbae-ib-vs-firebird-fb-differences.html).